# In C how do I dynamically add command line arguments to a string array?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, dynamic-arrays, argv, c-strings

At the moment the only way I can see it is by cycling through the argv argument list, getting the largest of the input strings and creating a new dynamic array with this largest size dictating the memory allocation for each element.

Or is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: Do you need copies, or can you use the originals? Because space was already allocated for them… Can you show what you are really trying to do; as it is, you make me think "huh? why not reference `argv` directly?"

Comment: There might be a more straightforward way but it requires a more straightforward explanation of what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to prepend another string to the initial argument list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following helps:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char** myStrings;
  int ii;
  myStrings = malloc(argc * sizeof *myStrings);
  for(ii = 0; ii < argc; ii++) {
    myStrings[ii] = malloc(strlen(argv[ii])+1);
    strcpy(myStrings[ii], argv[ii]);
  }
  for (ii = 0; ii < argc; ii++) {
    printf("copied argument %d: it is '%s'\n", ii, myStrings[ii]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you define your `main` with the signature as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

then, here `argv` is an array of pointers to strings passed as command line arguments. Quoting the C99 standard section 5.1.2.2.1 -

> The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv
>   array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored
>   values between program startup and program termination.

Therefore, you can either directly modify the strings pointed to by elements of `argv`, or  you can copy those strings and then process them.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *strlist[argc];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < argc) {
        strlist[i] = malloc(1 + strlen(argv[i]));
        if(strlist[i] == NULL) {
            printf("not enough memory to allocate\n");
            // handle it
        }
        strcpy(strlist[i], argv[i]);
        i++;
    }
    // process strlist
    // after you are done with it, free it
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        free(strlist[i]);
        strlist[i] = NULL;
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: IINM, strings pointed to by `argv` are modifiable. They certanly aren't string *literals*.

Comment: @jrok you are right. The C99 standard 5.1.2.2.1 says `The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall
be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.` Thanks :) I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is a 'string array' itself: it is an array of `char*`.

You can simply duplicate it (allocating memory for each element). Using a 2D array of `char` (as you suggest) for strings might be not a very efficient approach.

Comment: `char **my_argv = malloc(argc * sizeof(char*)); for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) { my_argv[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1); strcpy(my_argv[i], argv[i]); }` // This doesn't include 'NULL' string in the end of argv.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you want to achieve.

- You can use `argv` as it is. `argv` is already an array of string pointers.
- You can use a fixed size array, e.g. `char argv_copy[7][256]`. This means, you can use an array, which is large enough for the expected strings
- As you suggested, you can go through `argv` and look for the largest string.
- You can simply copy the `argv` structure, which means

  ```
  char **argv_copy = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(char*));
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
      argv_copy[i - 1] = malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
      strcpy(argv_copy[i - 1], argv[i]);
  }
  ```